# WCF -Android/Iphone interoperability

Tags: iphone, android, wcf, linq-to-sql, wsdualhttpbinding

I'm actually developing a client/server application : the client consumes a WCF service.

The client needs to get database data, so the WCF service returns Linq-to-SQL entities (`System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute`)

To implement a "push" communication from server to client, we are going to implement duplex contract with `WSDualHttpBinding`.

Here is my question : for the future, we think about developing mobile client (Android/iPhone), I did research about interoperability, but the answers were about using standards like REST that i don't use.

Is it possible to use my service (entities exchange + WSDual binding)?

Comment: If i want to implement push notifications, i' need to use a different API for each client type or do you know an universal standart usable by .net

Answer (score 0):

`WsDualHttpBinding` is .NET only (it can't be even consumed by Silverlight). It demands that your client host HTTP endpoint (= client must act as HTTP server). Push notification are either implemented through some specialized API (per client type) or client pools the service for notifications.

REST services are used because they sends smaller messages and their consuming on mobile devices is usually easier without need for some additional library.